# data icon position in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, icons

i want to add 3 data icon at the header of my page :

"*" -------- "**" ----------"*"

left------center-----right

I used class="ui-btn-left" for left icon

"ui-btn-right"  for right icon

"ui-btn-center" for centered icon

the problem was in the centered icon ,it didn't appear at the center , it's appear at new line at left side

what should i do ??

Comment: Show a sample of your non-working code

Comment: they don't allow to upload img !

Answer (score 0):

'ui-btn-center' doesn't work because it's not a supported class in the jQuery Mobile Framework.

You will have to add your own bit of CSS to make it work.

```
.ui-btn-center{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Try adding that and let me know if it works.